# Finding a Discrete Analog to Faà di Bruno's Formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

When looking back over some old calculus notes, I found a way to rearrange second and third order difference quotients in such a way that Faà di Bruno's formula for the second and third derivatives can be computed/proved/verified by directly taking limits of said rearrangements, instead of by iteratively applying the chain rule two or three times respectively. I had hoped to extended this observation to the fourth derivative and beyond, but as of writing I have been unable to do so. My question is based around ascertaining if such a generalisation is possible, and if so what form can we force any possible rearrangement to take?

When making this problem precise I have formulated my problem almost as a word problem (i.e. checking if $x = y$ in some algebra $\mathcal A$), but It takes the slightly different form of seeing if $x \in S$ for some $S \subseteq \mathcal A$. However the question could equally be posed in more elementary terms.

Apologies for the long length, this is mostly due to the size of the equations housed within, but there is some moderately long discussion also.

### Introduction

Suppose that one has a field $\mathbb K$ and  that $\mathbb U$, $\mathbb V$, and $\mathbb W$ are three $\mathbb K$-vector spaces with underlying sets $U,V,W$, respectively. Suppose also that $f:U \to V$ and $g:V \to W$ are functions of sets.

In doing calculus with the objects we have just introduced, it is helpful to define a few finite difference operators/quotients to represent quantities that we will later take limits of in order to calculate derivatives. Notably, we make the following definitions for finite differences $E$ and $Q$, where $S$ is some finite set, $\tau: S \to \mathbb K^*$, $h: S \to U$ and $p \in U$.

\begin{align}
E[f,h]_p & := \sum_{X \in \mathcal P(S)}(-1)^{\left|S \setminus X\right|} \cdot f\left(p + \sum_{x \in X}\tau_x \cdot h_x\right) \tag{1}\\\\
Q[f,\tau,h]_p & := \frac{E[f,\tau \cdot h]_p}{\prod_{s \in S}{\tau_s}}\\ &= \frac{1}{\prod_{s \in S}{\tau_s}}\sum_{X \in \mathcal P(S)}(-1)^{\left|S \setminus X\right|} \cdot f\left(p + \sum_{x \in X}\tau_x \cdot h_x\right) \tag{2}
\end{align}
Note that $E$ and $Q$ are highly symmetric with respects to permutation of $S$. Notably observe that (S.a) and (S.b) hold for any bijection $\sigma: S \stackrel\sim\to S$.
\begin{align}
E[f,h \circ \sigma ]_p = E[f,h ]_p \ \  \text{(S.a)} &&&& Q[f,\tau \circ \sigma,h \circ \sigma]_p= Q[f,\tau,h]_p \tag{S.b} 
\end{align}

Let $k = |S|$. Observe that for $k = 1$ one has that $Q[f,t,h]_p = \frac{f(p +th) - f(p)}{t}$, which is the 'usual' difference quotient of calculus. Additionally note for any $k \in \mathbb N_0$ that, should $f$ be in $C^{k}(U,V)$, one has that $\lim_{\tau \to 0} Q[f,\tau,h]_p = \left(\prod_{s \in S}\partial_{h_s}\right)f|_p$, which is the $k^\text{th}$ mixed partial of $f$ at $p$ with directions $h$. Here the limit of $ \tau \to 0$ is taken component-wise. We will denote this limiting value by $D[f,h]_p$. Note also that $D[f,h]_p$ is just equivalently the total derivative of $f$ at $p$  when seen as a function of the 'directions' $h$, and so the notation I supply is consistent with 'standard convention'. Note that in the above and all talk of limits in what follows, one would need the spaces $\mathbb U$, $\mathbb V$ and $\mathbb W$ to have at least the structure of topological vector spaces with $\mathbb K$ being a topological field. However: the specifics of the structure are not important for my question, and so are left indeterminate.

In the interest of making equations further down easier to read, we will make two further definitions (3) (4) that allow us to specify our differences $Q$ and $E$ with $\tau$ and $h$ given componentise:
\begin{align}
E[f|h_1,\ldots,h_k] &:= E[f,h] \tag{3}\\
Q[f|\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_k|h_1,\ldots,h_k] &:= Q[f,\tau,h] \tag{4}\\
\end{align}
Where $S := \{1,\ldots, k\}$, $\tau: S \to \mathbb K^* \  s \mapsto \tau_s$, and $h: S \to U \ s\mapsto h_s$ respectively. Now that we have defined our terms we can continue with the introduction and get to the motivation of my question:

Note firstly that when $k = 0$, then $S = \emptyset$ as well as $\tau$ and $h$ being uniquely defined with empty domain. The identity $gf(p) = gf(p)$ then may be written as equation (N), with  $\bar h: \emptyset \to V$ the unique empty function, and could be seen as a degenerative case of Faà di Bruno's formula for the $0^\text{th}$ derivative.

$$Q[g \circ f,\tau,h]_{p} = Q\big[g ,\tau,\bar h\big]_{f(p)} \tag{N}$$

Assume hence $f \in C^k(U,V)$ and $g \in C^k(V,W)$. Note that in the $k = 1$ case calculating the first directional derivative at a point $p \in U$ of $g\circ f$, in direction $h \in U$, we may be helped by the rearrangement $(I.a)$, where $t \in \mathbb K^*$:

\begin{align}
\frac{gf\left(p +th\right) - gf(p)}{t} &= \frac{g\left(f(p) + t\frac{f(p + th) - f(p)}{t}\right) - gf(p)}{t} \tag{I.a}\\
Q\left[g \circ f \ | \ t \ | \ h\right]_p &= Q\left[g \ | \ t \ | \ Q[f,t,h]_{p}\right]_{f(p)} \tag{I.b}
\end{align}

Note that the  rearrangement (I.a) is equivalent to (I.b) and is, of course, nothing new but is a key step in a standard  proof of the chain rule (for partial derivatives) yielding the identity $D[g\circ f,h]_p = D[g,D[f,h]_p]_{f(p)}$. What I am interested in is how equations of the form (I.b) evolve when $k > 1$. (specifically for $k >3$ as I have figured out all the cases $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and give  the remaining cases below for $k \in \{2,3\}$).

Note in the $k = 2$ case we can use an inductive argument with derivatives to prove that (5) holds. (For example we can see (5) as a special case of Faà di Bruno's formula).

$$D[g\circ f|h,h^\prime]_p = D\Big[g \ | \ D[f | h,h^\prime ]_p\Big]_{f(p)} + D\Big[g\ | \ D[f | h]_p, D[f | h]_p\Big]_{f(p)} \tag{5} $$

Curiously, we can also perform a rearrangement similar to that of (I.a) and (I.b) to give a proof of the identity (5) just by taking limits directly from the equation (II.a) or equivalently (II.b) as $t \to 0$ and $t^\prime \to 0$.

\begin{align}
\frac{gf(p +th +t^\prime h^\prime) - gf(p +th) - gf(p +t^\prime h^\prime) + gf(p)}{tt^\prime} &= \frac{g\left(\big(f(p +th) + f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p)\big) +  tt^\prime\frac{f(p + th + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p + th) - f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) +f(p)}{tt^\prime}\right) - g\big(f(p +th) + f(p +t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p)\big)}{t\cdot t^\prime} 
 + \frac{g\big(f(p) + t\frac{f(p + th) - f(p)}{t} + t^\prime\frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p)}{t^\prime}\big) - g \big(f(p) + t\frac{f(p + th) - f(p)}{t}\big) - g \big(f(p) + t^\prime\frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p)}{t^\prime}\big) + gf(p)}{t \cdot t^\prime } \tag{II.a}\\\\
Q\big[g \circ f\ | \ t,t^\prime \ | \ h,h^\prime\big]_p &= Q\Big[f ,\ t\cdot t^\prime 
 , Q[f \ | \ t,t^\prime \ | \ h,h^\prime]_p\Big]_{f(p + th) + f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p)} + Q\Big[g \ | \ t,t^\prime \ | \ Q[f,t,h]_p, Q[f,t^\prime,h^\prime]_p\Big]_{f(p)}\tag{II.b}
\end{align}

We have an analogues result for $k = 3$, only this time the equations involved have grown *a lot* to become rather bloated and unwieldy. Firstly note equation (6), another special case of Faà di Bruno's formula, this time for the third derivative:

\begin{equation}
D\Big[g \circ f \ | \ h,h^\prime, h^{\prime\prime}\Big]_p = D\Big[g,D\big[f \ | \ h,h^\prime,h^{\prime\prime}\big]_p\Big]_{f(p)} + D\Big[g \ | \ D\big[f,h\big]_p, D\big[f \ | \ h^\prime,h^{\prime\prime}\big]_p\Big]_{f(p)} + D\Big[g \ |\  D\big[f,h^\prime\big]_p, D\big[f \ | \ h^{\prime\prime},h\big]_p\Big]_{f(p)} + D\Big[g \ | \ D\big[f,h^{\prime\prime}\big]_p, D\big[f \ | \ h,h^{\prime}\big]_p\Big]_{f(p)} + D\Big[g \ | \ D\big[f,h\big]_p,D\big[f,h^\prime\big]_p,D\big[f,h^{\prime\prime}\big]_p\Big]_{f(p)} \tag{6}
\end{equation}

Observe then the two corresponding rearrangements of our difference quotient $Q$, given as (III.a) and (III.b). Note that I have tried to format the equations a best as I can. However due to their extremely large size they maybe difficult to display on mathematics stack exchange, even with the horizontal scroll bar. I have found [a very useful website](https://arachnoid.com/latex/) for rendering large mathjax that seems to do a better job for the two equations. One can copy my mathjax using the menu opened by right clicking on them. One can then copy into the website (or a $\LaTeX$ program) and remove the ampersand to get a better view. Unfortunately I can't just give a link because that is susceptible to link-rot. Note that taking the limit as $t \to 0$, $t^\prime \to 0$, and $t^{\prime \prime} \to 0$ one recovers equation (6).
\begin{align}
\frac{gf\left(p + th +t^\prime h^\prime + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}\right) - gf\left(p + th + t^\prime h^\prime\right) - gf\left(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}\right) - gf\left(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime} + th\right) + gf(p + th) + gf(p + t^\prime h^\prime) + gf(p + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - gf(p)}{t\cdot t^\prime \cdot t^{\prime\prime}}
&= \frac{g\Big(\big(f(p + th + t^\prime h^\prime) + f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) +  f(p + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime} + th) - f(p + th) - f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}) + f(p)\big) + \frac{f( +th + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p + th + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) -  f(p + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime} + th) + f(p + th) + f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) + f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p)}{t^{}t^\prime t^{\prime \prime}}\Big) - g\Big(f(p + th + t^\prime h^\prime) + f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) +  f(p + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime} + th) - f(p + th) - f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}) + f(p)\Big)}{t\cdot t^\prime \cdot t^{\prime\prime}} 
+
\frac{g\left(f(p + th) + t t^\prime \frac{f(p + th + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p + th) - f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) + f(p)}{t^{}t^\prime} + t^{\prime\prime}\frac{f(p + th + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p+ th)}{t^{\prime\prime}}\right) - g\left(f(p + th) + t t^\prime \frac{f(p + th + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p + th) - f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) + f(p) }{t^{}t^\prime}\right) - g\left(f(p + th) + t^{\prime\prime}\frac{f(p + th + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p+ th)}{t^{\prime\prime}}\right) + gf(p + th)}{t\cdot t^\prime \cdot t^{\prime\prime}}
+
\frac{g\left(f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) + t^{\prime} t^{\prime\prime} \frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p + t^\prime 
 h^\prime) - f(p + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) + f(p)}{t^{\prime}t^{\prime\prime}} + t^{}\frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{} h^{}) - f(p+ t^\prime h^\prime)}{t^{}}\right) - g\left(f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) + t^\prime t^{\prime\prime} \frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) + f(p) }{t^{\prime}t}\right) - g\left(f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) + t^{}\frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{} h^{}) - f(p+ t^\prime h^\prime)}{t^{}}\right) + gf(p + t^\prime h^\prime)}{t\cdot t^\prime \cdot t^{\prime\prime}}
+
\frac{g\left(f(p + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) + t^{\prime\prime} t\frac{f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime} + th) - f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p + th) + f(p)}{t^{\prime\prime}t} + t^{\prime}\frac{f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime} + t^{\prime} h^{\prime}) - f(p+ t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime})}{t^{\prime}}\right) - g\left(f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}) + t^{\prime\prime} t \frac{f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime} + th) - f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p + th) + f(p) }{t^{\prime\prime}t^{}}\right) - g\left(f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}) + t^{\prime}\frac{f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime} + t^{\prime} h^{\prime}) - f(p+ t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime})}{t^{\prime}}\right) + gf(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime})}{t^{}\cdot t^\prime \cdot t^{\prime\prime}}
+
\frac{g\Big(f(p) + t^{\prime\prime}\frac{f(p + th + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p+ th)}{t^{\prime\prime}} + t^{\prime}\frac{f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime} + t^{\prime} h^{\prime}) - f(p+ t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime})}{t^{\prime}} + t^{}\frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{} h^{}) - f(p+ t^\prime h^\prime)}{t^{}} \Big) - g\Big(f(p) + t^{\prime}\frac{f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime} + t^{\prime} h^{\prime}) - f(p+ t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime})}{t^{\prime}} + t^{}\frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{} h^{}) - f(p+ t^\prime h^\prime)}{t^{}} \Big) - g\Big(f(p) + t^{\prime\prime}\frac{f(p + th + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p+ th)}{t^{\prime\prime}} + t^{}\frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{} h^{}) - f(p+ t^\prime h^\prime)}{t^{}} \Big) - g\Big(f(p) + t^{\prime\prime}\frac{f(p + th + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p+ th)}{t^{\prime\prime}} + t^{\prime}\frac{f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime} + t^{\prime} h^{\prime}) - f(p+ t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime})}{t^{\prime}} \Big) + g\Big(f(p) + t^{\prime\prime}\frac{f(p + th + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) - f(p+ th)}{t^{\prime\prime}} \Big) + g\Big(f(p) + t^{\prime}\frac{f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime} + t^{\prime} h^{\prime}) - f(p+ t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime})}{t^{\prime}}\Big) + g\Big(f(p) + t^{}\frac{f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{} h^{}) - f(p+ t^\prime h^\prime)}{t^{}} \Big) - gf(p)}{t^{}\cdot t^\prime \cdot t^{\prime\prime}}
\tag{III.a}\\\\\\
Q\left[g \circ f\ | \ t,t^\prime,t^{\prime\prime} \ | \ h,h^\prime,h^{\prime\prime}\right]_p = Q \Big[g,t^{}t^\prime t^{\prime\prime}, D\big[f \ | \ t,t^\prime, t^{\prime\prime} \ | \ h, h^\prime, h^{\prime\prime}\big]_p\Big]_{f(p + th + t^\prime h^\prime) +f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^{\prime\prime} h^{\prime\prime}) + f(p + t^\prime h^\prime + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p + th) - f(p + t^\prime h^\prime) - f(p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}) + f(p)}
 +  Q\Big[g \ |t^{}t^\prime, t^{\prime\prime} \ | \ D\big[f \ | \ t,t^\prime \ | \ h,h^\prime \big]_{p}, D\big[f,t^{\prime\prime},h^{\prime\prime}\big]_{p + th} \Big]_{p + th}
 +  Q\Big[g \ |t^{\prime}t^{\prime\prime}, t^{} \ | \ D\big[f \ | \ t^{\prime}t^{\prime\prime} \ | \ h^\prime,h^{\prime\prime} \big]_{p}, D\big[f,t^{},h^{}\big]_{p + t^\prime h^\prime} \Big]_{p + t^\prime h^\prime}
 +  Q\Big[g \ |t^{\prime}t^{}, t^{\prime} \ | \ D\big[f \ | \ t^{\prime}t^{} \ | \ h^{\prime}, h^{} \big]_{p}, D\big[f,t^{\prime},h^{\prime}\big]_{p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}} \Big]_{p + t^{\prime\prime}h^{\prime\prime}}
+ Q\Big[g \ | \  t,t^\prime, t^{\prime\prime} \ | \ D\big[f,h\big]_{p + h^\prime}, D\big[f,h^\prime\big]_{p + h^{\prime\prime}},D\big[f,h^{\prime\prime}\big]_{p + h}\Big]_{f(p)}\tag{III.b}
\end{align}

Looking at all four cases of $k$, we see that one has achieved an identity of the form (IV). Equation (IV) may be seen as a discrete variant of Faà di Bruno's formula, or at the very least a version that exists before the usual limits have been taken when one computes derivatives. In (IV), $\ \Pi(S)$ is the set of all partitions of the set $S$,  as well as  $T_P: P \to \mathbb K^* \ X \mapsto \prod_{x \in X}\tau_x$, $H_P: P \to V$ and $q: \Pi(S) \to U$ being some functions.

$$
Q\big[g \circ f, \tau, h\big]_p = \sum_{P \in \Pi(S)} Q\Big[g,T_P,H_P\Big]_{q_P} \tag{IV}
$$

Furthermore, $H_P$ has the structure such that  $H_P(X) = D\big[f,\tau|_X, h|_X\big]_{r_{P,X}}$ for all $X \in P$ for some $r_P: P \to U$, leading to the equation $D\big[g \circ f, \tau, h\big]_p = \sum_{P \in \Pi(S)}  \Big[g,T_P, \lambda X. D\big[f,\tau|_X, h|_X\big]_{r_{P,X}}\Big]_{q_P} $, here given using $\lambda$-function notation. Lastly we can make note that $r_{P,X}$ can further be decomposed to being of the form $\sum_{a \in A} \sigma_a f(p + \sum_{i \in A}h_a )$ for some $A \subseteq S$ and $\sigma: A \to \{-1,+1\}$ satisfying $\sum_{a \in A}\sigma_a = 1$ for each $P$ and $X$.

Note that the $k = 2$ case is completely symmetric  with respect to permutation of difference terms. What I mean by this is that for any coherent  permutation of the terms $\{h,h^\prime\}$ and $\{t,t^\prime\}$, all the terms in the right hand side of (II.b) are fixed. Observe that analogous statements are true in the $k = 1$ and $k = 0$ cases due to there only being the identity permutation available on sets of cardinality at most one. Note that the $k = 3$ case seems a little more asymmetric, but I can't currently codify how this is so.

My question involves asking the question of whether it is possible to choose $q$, and $H$ such that (IV) holds when $k \geq 4$, or if failing that some other reasonable form for $D\big[g \circ f, \tau, h\big]_p$ may be given? Note additionally that (IV) is equivalent to $E\big[g \circ f, h\big]_p = \sum_{P \in \Pi(S)}E\Big[g,H_P\Big]_{q_P}$, which removes the explicit dependence on the field $\mathbb K$ and makes equations less cumbersome. We will thus state our question in terms of $E$ and not $Q$.

What these above cases provide is a potential pathway for an alternative proof of Faà di Bruno's formula where instead of one inductively taking derivatives to prove the required identities, one crafts an equation between difference quotients for each $k$, and then takes limits at the end. I am very interested to see how far this methodology can be pushed. (Note I am already confident in the proof of Faà di Bruno's formula and my question is not chiefly about calculus, only motivated by it). To this end I would like to know when such rearrangements of difference quotient are possible. The fine detail of this question is given below:

---

### Precise Problem Statement

My question can be posed formally as a word problem:

Suppose that $k \in \mathbb N_0$. Let $\mathrm U:\mathbb K\text{-}\mathbf{Vect} \to \mathbf {Set} $ be the forgetful functor and Let $ \mathrm F: \mathbf {Set} \to \mathbb K\text{-}\mathbf{Vect} $ be a corresponding  free functor / right adjoint. Furthermore Let $\hat p$ and $\left(\hat s_i\right)_{i \in \mathbb N_0}$ be distinct symbols, as well as letting $\hat S = \{\hat s_1, \ldots, \hat s_k\}$ be a set of $k$ distinct elements. Furthermore let the space $\mathcal A := \mathrm F(G)$ be the free algebra generated by the set $G := \{\hat p\} \cup \hat S $, with $\hat \chi: G \to \mathrm U(\mathcal A)$ the unit map. Additionally let $\mathcal B := \mathrm{FU}(\mathcal A)$ and $\mathcal C := \mathrm {FU}(\mathcal B)$ with the respective units $\hat f: U \mathcal A \to U \mathcal B$ $\hat g: U \mathcal B \to U \mathcal C$ respectively. Let $\hat{h} = \chi|_{\hat{S}}: \hat S \to \mathcal A$. In what follows we will use angle brackets $\langle\  \cdot \ \rangle  $ to denote generated vector space, and squared brackets $[ \ \cdot \ ]$ to denote the generated additive subgroup.

Now for $X,Y \subseteq \mathrm U \left(\mathcal A\right)$ and $X^\prime,Y^\prime \subseteq \mathrm U \left(\mathcal A\right)$, define $\delta_0(X,Y)$ and $\delta_1(X^\prime,Y^\prime)$ by:

\begin{align}
\delta_0(X,Y) &= \left\{b \in \mathcal B \ | \ \exists r \in X \  \exists T \text{ finite } \ \exists l: T \to Y : b = E[\hat{f},l]_r\right\}\\
\delta_1(X^\prime,Y^\prime) &= \left\{c \in \mathcal C \ | \ \exists r \in X^\prime \  \exists T \text{ finite } \ \exists l: T \to Y^\prime : c = E[\hat{g},l]_r\right\}
\end{align}

Set also $\epsilon_0(Z)$ and $\epsilon_1(Z^\prime)$ for $Z \subseteq \mathrm U\mathcal A$ and $Z^\prime \subseteq \mathrm U\mathcal B$
\begin{align}
\epsilon_0(Z) &=\left\{a \in \mathcal A \ | \ \exists T \text{ finite } \exists \sigma: T \to \{-1,1\} \ \exists l: T \to Z\left[ \sum_{t \in T}\sigma_t = 1 \land a = \sum_{t \in T}\sigma_tl_t\right]\right\}\\
\epsilon_1(Z^\prime) &=\left\{b \in \mathcal B \ | \ \exists T \text{ finite } \exists \sigma: T \to \{-1,1\} \ \exists l: T \to Z^\prime \left[ \sum_{t \in T}\sigma_t = 1 \land b = \sum_{t \in T}\sigma_tl_t\right]\right\}
\end{align}

We can finally ask our question: *where on this increasingly strict hierarchy of sets below can $E\left[\hat g \circ \hat f, \hat{h}\right]_{\hat{p}}$ be made to lie*?

1. Is $E\left[\hat g \circ \hat f, \hat{h}\right]_{\hat{p}} \in \langle \delta_1(\mathcal B,\mathcal B)\rangle$?
2. Is $E\left[\hat g \circ \hat f, \hat{h}\right]_{\hat{p}} \in \left\langle \delta_1\left(\epsilon_1\left(\hat{f}\left(\hat p + [\hat{h}(\hat S)]\right)\right),\delta_0\left(\hat p + [\hat{h}(\hat S)],\hat{h}(\hat S)\right)\right)\right\rangle$?
3. Do there exist a family $\left(H_P: P \to \mathcal B\right)_{P \in \Pi(S)}$ and $\hat{q}: \Pi(S) \to \mathcal A $ such that $E\left[g \circ f, \hat{h}\right]_{\hat{p}} = \sum_{P \in \Pi(S)}E\Big[\hat{g}, H_P\Big]_{\hat{q}_P}$, where $H_P(X) \in \epsilon_1\left(\big\{H \in \mathcal B \ | \ \exists q \in \hat p + [\hat{h}(\hat S)]: H = E\left[\bar{f} \ | \ h|_{X}\right]_{q}\big\}\right)$ and $\hat{q}_P \in \epsilon_1\left(\hat{f}\left(\hat p + [\hat{h}(\hat S)]\right)\right)$?

Furthermore, if any of the above hold true is there an effective method of computing the required presentation. I suspect that for a positive answer to any of the above queries then  one immediately gets this computation: as the only way I can imagine a proof is a direct one, i.e. by directly writing down a correct formula, but perhaps there is some indirect argument one could make. I will now explain the rational behind the different levels of the hierarchy:

(1.) is the weakest assertion we can hope for. It asserts that any difference quotient $E$ (or resp. $Q$) of $g \circ f$ can be re-written in terms of difference quotients purely made from $g$ (of any order and in any direction).

(2.) makes stronger requirements on our ansatz, by trying to adhere to  some of the form of the original Faà di Bruno's formula / chain rule. Notably, the fact that all of the difference term's base points should be approximately $\hat f( \hat p)$, and the directions should all be difference terms of $f$ in the directions  of $\hat {h}$, with furthermore the latter difference terms be based approximately around the point $\hat p$.

(3.) Is the strongest assertion / most naïve form we can hope for, i.e. one that is the closest possible to the original Faà di Bruno's formula. (see below for discussion of why we cannot search for a simpler solution).

As an aside one can always ask whether or not one can achieve an exact porting of Faà di Bruno's formula to our discrete context, i.e. having that $E\left[g \circ f,h\right]_p = \sum_{P \in \Pi(S)}E\left[g,\lambda X. E\left[f,h|_X\right]_{f(p)}\right]_p$ holds. However, this is demonstrably untrue and the first counterexample is achieved in the $k = 2$ case.

I also have supplementary questions regarding symmetry: notably how symmetric with respects to  permutation of $\hat S$ can our decomposition be made? I know on Maths S.E. one should only have one question per post, so this supplementary question need not be pondered or addressed in any response, it is mere food for thought. Bedsides, I currently am unable to formally state such a question about symmetry.

The reason why I pose my question with free functors is because I am looking for a
'universal solution'. I mean in the sense that, for the $p \in U$ and $s_1,\ldots, s_k \in S$ of our initial problem formulation, then for the map $\chi: G \to U$ given by $\hat p \mapsto p$ and $ \hat s_k \mapsto s_k$, using the commutative diagram below: one can achieve a solution for all $\mathbb K$-vector spaces, $f: U \to V$, $g: V \to W$, and $h: S \to U$ in a uniform way. In the commutative datagram, all the  vertical maps $!$ are the ones afforded by the universal property of the associated unit. One could conceivably pose this question without such lofty structure, but there is a certain 'neatness' to it that I like.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G  @>{\hat \chi}>> {\mathcal A} @>{\hat f}>> {\mathcal B} @>{\hat g}>> {\mathcal C}\\
@| @VV!V @VV!V @VV!V\\
G @>{\chi}>> U @>{f}>> V @>{g}>> W
\end{CD}

---

### What I have tried

My main method of attacking this problem has just been inspection. In particular, the $k = 0 $ case is trivial. The $k = 1$ case is a known result as mentioned before. The $k = 2$ case is discussed much more rarely. I have technically seen it before (on math s.e. to be precise) however I cannot find the source again and have not seen it elsewhere. Discovering this equation (II.b) was the onramp to my study. The $k = 3$ case I have not seen anywhere before, though not to say that it is novel. Discovering this equation took me about a week of on and off thought and trial and error until I eventually spotted something that would allow enough cancellation to give a positive result to my question. I have tried to attack the $k = 4$ case with the same naivety, however it seems *much* more complex and after a lot of thought I have come up with nothing useful other then a realising that balancing the number of $gf(p)$ terms in any candidate expression is difficult (for me to achieve). (note: when writing up this question I believe I have made some more progress on finding a bespoke solution for the $k = 4$ case; I will add a community wiki response if fruitful).

I also have tried adapting a couple of proofs of Faà di Bruno's formula: All the proofs I have seen of Faà di Bruno's formula rely on iteratively differentiating partial derivatives, and only differed in the details of how they justified their equations. I had hoped, that I could mimic the proofs, but instead simply just iteratively applied the difference operator $Q$ and spotted some rearrangements I could perform at each step I could concoct some closed form expression of the required form. However, after staring at the problem for a few hours and much chicken scratch workings I have come up fruitless in this avenue... or so I thought: doing some more doodling whilst I worked on this question has given me a hopeful argument for a solution of the form (2.). I am working on making a community wiki answer giving more detail. Note though that even If this method works, I do not believe it will give solutions of the nicest form (3.).

It did cross my mind to try to brute force the $k = 4$ problem by writing a program, but I'm pretty sure it is computationally infeasible with the number of variables in the system. Besides, the only program that I know how to use symbolic manipulation for is maple - which I don't have a licence for at this time!

---

This concludes my question. Hopefully I have made my problem clear, though It is a little bit of a an odd question requiring some indirection to state. Thus if there is anything that upon reading is unclear, please don't hesitate to ask! I believe there is some justification in the hope of a positive answer to this question, due the the implicit connection between my problem and Faà di Bruno's formula, though I currently  have no theory that allows me to be certain.

Comment: For higher derivatives, there is also the Grünwald-Letnikov derivative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnwald%E2%80%93Letnikov_derivative

Comment: You could use Sage (sagemath).

Comment: @IV_, thanks for the search term on the GL derivative. Unfortunately, despite being easier to work with the fact that all the directions  $h$ 's converge synchronously makes this too specific for my needs (I wish to produce formulae for all higher order differences in all directions, not just those on the diagonal). I will definitely look into Sage once I have finished with my current lines of inquiry. Thanks!

Comment: There are also multivariate Grunwald-Letnikov derivatives.

Comment: @IV_ Great, will look into!